# How do I create a view for a single node?

Tags: views, nodes

I have a *Company details* content type used to create 20 nodes. I created a view for that content type which displays all its nodes.

I want to create a view for a single node. Is it possible? How?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! :-) Of course you can. But depends on the context if this makes any sense. We don't know the context. Display single nodes in a Views block? Or what exactly are you trying to achieve? Please edit your question and add more context info. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the item at /node/{node_id}. If you need the item in a view, you can add a filter to the view for the node's id.